Fujitsu TX1320 M3 Windows Server fails to start after installation
Fujitsu Primergy TX1320 M3 with Windows Server 2019.
Yesterday after one week use Windows failed. It asked to install Windows again. It is configured as RAID 1 on an avago megaraid controller on two 300 GB disks.
This has occurred three times. I see available disk size 0 and user 300 GB, although the real space was less than 100 GB. Has anyone had the same experience? I followed doc specs on configuration RAID and did the following:
Initialize each disk. Configure a virtual drive as RAID 1 and install Windows.
